# How to install Windows Drivers properly?

Tags: windows, drivers, graphics-card, operating-systems

Recently I ran into a problem of blue screen of death(bsod) in windows and it seems like it may have occurred for driver problem. I am reinstalling my windows and want to follow proper way to install windows driver. So, I want your suggestion that how can I do that properly.

### The thinks I want to know is:

1. Should I download the drivers from the website of the manufacturers (in my case Asus). Aren't they outdated?
2. Should I use device manager to update the drivers? Does it update the drivers properly? Does it show all the drivers?
3. Should I use use third party application as **(IObit driver booster)**? May they mess-up the driver?
4. I recently added mouse and headset. As I learned the mismatched h/w and driver can cause the bsod problem what can I do with those drivers? Windows installed the mouse driver by itself and recently IObit gave a update of Realtek audio driver.
5. when windows is installed it installs drivers itself. Are those proper drivers?
6. Should I use **NVIDIA GeForce Experience** app for NVIDIA graphics driver update?

Comment: If you're installing Windows 10, the only drivers that need to be manually installed are CPU-related drivers (chipset, IMEI, thermal management, etc.).  CPU drivers must be installed first, immediately following OOBE _(or while in Audit mode)_, prior to any other drivers, software, or Windows Updates.  Once these are installed, connect to the internet and run Windows Updates, which will auto-install all other hardware drivers.  If not using Windows 10, the OEM will list the order of hardware driver installation, usually: Chipset > IMEI > Graphics > Audio > Network > any others

Comment: I found IMEI and Thermal management. Can you say which one is chipset?[link](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/X555LN/HelpDesk_Download/)

Comment: The chipset driver is listed under the Chipset category - X555LN is listed under Windows 10, whereas the X55LNB is listed under Windows 8.1 _(Chipset drivers aren't OS-specific, they're CPU-specific, so I'm not sure why ASUS is listing the latter only under Win8.1)_

Comment: Ok.One more help. Why do I need those drivers to be installed manually. doesn't Windows 10 install them by itself as other drivers?__ I am saying this because when I tested the chipset driver by trying to install it, It showed me there is a newer version installed already. But I am very sure I never installed a chipset driver.

Comment: AFAIK, the only drivers Windows Update cannot install are CPU-related drivers, likely because it's simply too complex to remotely manage, while also potentially creating a liability issue for Microsoft. You can view when it was installed by navigating to `Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features` and looking at the _Installed On_ column, and you're machine would be the first I personally have come across that installed Chipset drivers via Windows Update, especially since _(unless something's changed)_ they must be installed first, prior to any other drivers, software, or Windows Updates.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

Drivers published by Microsoft via Windows Update are not usually the most recent, but they are usually the most compatible and stable.

Drivers published directly by the OEM (usually linked on their site) are usually going to have the most recent features, but could be less stable, sometimes.

I've rarely had any issues with drivers from major OEMs from either source.

Figuring out what is causing a specific BSOD is going to be found by looking at the Event Viewer. There are plenty of questions here with answers that talk about diagnosing BSODs.

Comment: @Shuvo - That isn’t a Super User question.  You will have to wait til the Server Fault community answers your question.  You should have asked that question here instead of a subjective question like this question honestly.  Unfortunately that question doesn’t contain the necessary information to answer it

Comment: AFAIK, Windows Updated on Windows 10 uses the most recent WHQL drivers available; the only caveat is drivers that have been customized by the OEM (usually only GPU drivers) are locked to the OEM version due to those customizations the generic versions lack.